# Do large Airliners use full thrust when reversers are deployed?

Tags: braking, thrust-reverser

Do large and heavy Airliners, Jumbos and Super Jumbos wide bodies included use full thrust for braking when reversers are deployed?  What is the thrust setting?

Comment: related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/3660/1467

Comment: The answers given below don’t really specify how much actual thrust the engine produces when “max reverse thrust” is selected. I have a hunch it is considerably less than full rated “forward” thrust.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flight manual procedures and operators‘ policies notwithstanding, they would typically use full reverse thrust when the stopping performance requires so, and idle reverse thrust when not. The latter setting means less wear on the engines and lower noise. The former setting overrides these considerations when safety demands it.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on...
* the manufacturer's recommendations,
* the operator's policies,
* the airport's procedures,
* the Captain's wishes.

A 747 landing in LHR will probably only use Reverse Idle, whereas landing on a classicly-Caribbean airport may go to Full Reverse.

And the A380 only has 2 reversers, so that may affect the policy on that aircraft.

Comment: Unless, of course, the Heathrow 747 is landing on an icy runway...

Answer (score 0):

Thrust reverser works best on contaminated runways. On a relatively dry runway, full vs idle thrust reverse has negligible effect on braking. However, on icy runways, full trust reverse has a much greater effect on stopping distance. This information comes from the Airbus operational manuals.

Comment: One could quibble about "works best" vs "makes the most difference," but whichever phrasing is used, the basic point that TR's are most useful on contaminated runways is correct. It would be helpful to use that fact to reach an answer to the stated question, which is ***how*** TR's are used in practice.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the title or body questions.